# how to find if value exists or not in array of items with nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

write a function to return value true if 'monkey' not exits in array.

```
 const entities = [
           {
              id: 1,
              name: 'cat',
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: 'dog',
            },
            {
              id: 1,
              name: 'pig',
            },
    ];
const selection = 'monkey';
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: @kumar: it's so simple.You just write loop and check.

Comment: i need it in lodash, i have 50 objects in my array and which hits more than 4 or 5 times in a page level

Comment: @kumar Why do you need in lodash? Why don't you mention that in the question?

Answer (score 3):

**ES6**

```
entities.some((entity) => entity.name === selection);
```

**Lodash**

```
_.some(entities, ['name', selection]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample piece of code. Add the below code snippet in a function, call it. It gives your desired output.

```
for(var i=0;i<entities.length;i++){
   if(entities[i].name == 'monkey')
      return true;
   else 
      continue;
}
return false;
```

Comment: i need it in lodash @Jayanth

Answer (score 0):

Given into consideration that your array will contain the objects you mentioned, you can do something like this

```
private function _inArray(arr, value, key = "name"): boolean {
    let found: boolean = false;
    arr.some((obj) => {
       return (found = obj[key] == value);
    });
    return found;
}
...
...
myFunc() {
    const entities = [
       {
          id: 1,
          name: 'cat',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'dog',
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'pig',
        },
    ];
    const selection = 'monkey';
    this._inArray(entities, selection);
    //Since you need it in lodash here it is
    _.some(entities, ['name', 'monkey']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an es2015 solution.

```
  const entities = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'cat',
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'dog',
},
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'pig',
},
];


function doesntContainMonkey() {
    return !entities.find(x=>x.name === 'monkey');
}

doesntContainMonkey(); //true
```

Comment: it won't give single return value.. for every item in find level gives you a return...and two '!' gives you a true value .. then what is the use of two negations

Comment: if it finds a value then it return that value otherwise undefined with the two `!` you cast it simply to bool(true|false)

Comment: write a function to return value true if 'monkey' not exits in array.

Comment: thats equal to this right? return entities.find(x=>x.name === value)

Comment: no, that returns the actual object or undefined, i'll update the answer for your specific case

Answer (score 0):

```
function searchInArray(s, a, prop) {

    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        if(a[i][prop] === s) return i;

    }

    return false;

}
```

Usage:

```
searchInArray("monkey", entities, "name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
var index=entities.findIndex(x=>x.name==selection);

if(index == -1)//-1 means the searched item is not present.
  return true;
else
  return false;
```